# SQL Join using multiple columns and LAST date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:

Table A:

```
CUSTOMER  MATERIAL      DATE
X                Y      2021-01-01
X                Y      2021-02-01
X                Y      2021-03-01
X                Y      2021-04-01
X                Y      2021-05-01
X                Y      2021-06-01
```

and table B:

```
CUSTOMER  MATERIAL   PRICE_LIST     DATE
X                Y           10     2021-01-01
X                Y           11     2021-01-10
X                Y           15     2021-04-15
```

The expected output would be:

```
CUSTOMER  MATERIAL    DATE        PRICE_LIST
X                Y    2021-01-01          10
X                Y    2021-02-01          11
X                Y    2021-02-01          11
X                Y    2021-02-01          11
X                Y    2021-02-01          15
X                Y    2021-02-01          15
```

I need the last PRICE_LIST from B where A.DATE >= B.DATE

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.MATERIAL = B.MATERIAL
AND A.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER
AND A.DATE >= B.DATE
```

But it takes random values of PRICE_LIST where the other conditions matches

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question to be more clear. I can't tag the database, sorry

Comment: You can't add tag like "postgres" or "mysql" ?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment at first. Edited with google-bigquery tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery)

```
select any_value(a).*, 
  array_agg(price_list order by b.date desc limit 1)[offset(0)] as price_list
from tableA a
left join tableB b
using(customer, material)
where a.date >= b.date 
group by to_json_string(a)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: awesome Mikhail , that's what I needed